# Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-email-editor' in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I installed vue-email-editor in my project, But I got the below error when trying to use vue-email-editor in my Laravel vuejs project:

Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-email-editor'. '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/textiletoday/node_modules/vue-email-editor/dist/vue-email-editor.common.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/vue-email-editor` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vue-email-editor';`ts(7016).

When I run this "npm i --save-dev @types/vue-email-editor" I got the below error

npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2Fvue-email-editor - Not found

npm ERR! 404

npm ERR! 404  '@types/vue-email-editor@*' is not in this registry.

npm ERR! 404

npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a

npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2023-02-23T06_35_02_174Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 0):

The `vue-email-editor` doesn't export Typescript types.
Neither it has types declared in the `@types/` repository.

In this case, to avoid complaints from Typescript, you have to declare the types yourself.

It can be as simple as doing:

```js
// vue-email-editor.d.ts
declare module 'vue-email-editor'
```

Comment: I did it. But not working.

Comment: Be sure this file in included in Typescript's scope (`included` property in tsconfig.json). Take a look at this article for more informations: https://medium.com/@steveruiz/using-a-javascript-library-without-type-declarations-in-a-typescript-project-3643490015f3

Comment: There is no tsconfig.json file

Comment: A `tsconfig.json` file is required in any Typescript project. Your error is Typescript related. So that doesn't make much sense.